# Armstrong number with loop - c++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to let the user enter a number, tell them if it's [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) or not then ask them if they want to repeat this again.
I tried to write it many times but it didn't work!
when I enter 153, it gives me "it's not an Armstrong number." (in else statement)
I really messed up, I don't know what to do :"(

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
    int number, sum=0, num;
    double y;
    char x;

    cout << "Enter a number to check if it is an Armstrong number: ";
    cin >> number;
    num = number;
    while (number != 0) {
    y = number%10;
    number = number / 10;
    sum = sum + pow(y,3);

    if (sum == num) 
    cout << num << "is an Armstrong number.";
    else
    cout << num << "is not an Armstrong number.";

    cout << "do you want to continue? (y/n)";
    cin >> x;
    switch (x){
    case 'Y':
    case 'y': continue; break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n': cout << "bye"; break;
     }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can't break a `while` loop using `break` inside a `switch` statement. In addition, you need two loops here - an outer loop in order to scan the number, and an inner loop in order to check the number.

Comment: In short, close the `while` loop with a `}` after the assignment `sum = sum + pow(y,3)`.

Comment: Also, you'll need to count the length of the number, currently you'll only work for 3 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted has several problems that are not immediately apparent because of the incorrect formatting. Formatting matters to humans because it makes apparent the control flow of the program. Here is a section of your code reformatted (with clang-format) so you can observe the problem:

```
while (number != 0) {
    y = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
    sum = sum + pow(y, 3);

    if (sum == num)
        cout << num << "is an Armstrong number.";
    else
        cout << num << "is not an Armstrong number.";
//...
```

It should be apparent from this that you are testing whether the number is an Armstrong number in the middle of the computation. The code should probably read like this:

```
while (number != 0) {
    y = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
    sum = sum + pow(y, 3);
}    

if (sum == num)
    cout << num << "is an Armstrong number.";
else
    cout << num << "is not an Armstrong number.";
```

Of course you also need an outer loop to ask the user whether to continue or not.

Also, your test assumes 3 digits which is not necessarily true since 1634 is also an Armstrong number. You'll need to count the digits. Here is the complete solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

static int digit_count(int num);
static int armstrong_sum(int num);
static bool ask_yes_no(const char* question);

int main() {
  do {
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a number to check if it is an Armstrong number: ";
    cin >> num;
    if (num == armstrong_sum(num))
      cout << num << " is an Armstrong number." << endl;
    else
      cout << num << " is NOT an Armstrong number." << endl;
  } while (ask_yes_no("do you want to continue?"));
  cout << "bye" << endl;
  return 0;
}

int digit_count(int num) {
  int count = 0;
  for (; num != 0; num /= 10) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}

int armstrong_sum(int num) {
  int sum = 0;
  int count = digit_count(num);
  for (; num != 0; num /= 10) {
    sum += static_cast<int>(pow(num % 10, count));
  }
  return sum;
}

bool ask_yes_no(const char* question) {
  for (;;) {
    char x;
    cout << question << " (y/n)";
    cin >> x;
    if (x == 'y' || x == 'Y')
      return true;
    else if (x == 'n' || x == 'N')
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! now I understand why the output was wrong :)